# Linux Libertine O: Ligatures? | XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, fontspec, csquotes

I'm currently studying the fontspec documentation, for a project I'm doing.

I've found an issue, where neither ligatures (all except `TeX`) work, nor numbers in the `OldStyle` option work with the Linux Libertine O font.
Additionally, quotes in the ‘british’ style, don't work either, although I'm not sure if that has something to do with the font.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[main=ngerman,british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\defaultfontfeatures[Linux Libertine O]{
    UprightFont={*},
    BoldFont= {* Bold},
    ItalicFont={* Italic},
    BoldItalicFont={* Bold Italic},
    Ligatures={Common},
    Numbers={OldStyle},
}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}
fi fh fl ff tz st ct
    \selectlanguage{british}
\enquote{enquoted text}
\end{document}
```

Comment: add `\XeTeXtracingfonts=1`  and then show the log-file.

Comment: Hm, lots of warnings. https://pastebin.com/XZVaTe86

Comment: Why do you think that this is the relevant part of the log?

Comment: Because that's the part I understand. Thank you for that rectification, here's the whole log. https://pastebin.com/Z8tawFcQ

Comment: that is not the log file, it is the terminal output. (And just in case: the \XeTeXtracingfonts=1  must be early in the file).

Comment: I have put the \XeTeXtracingfonts=1 before the \begin{document}. I'm on the app ‘VerbTeX’ on mobile. There is merely a document.aux file (which is mentioned at the end of the paste in the previous comment), and a document.out file, which contains nothing.

Comment: oh, well.  Well on my current texlive the fonts work fine. As far as I can see this VerbTeX processes your files on some server. So ask their support what is wrong with the font files they use.

Comment: @Concerto in VerbTeX the log file is also available. First you need to compile (the `GENERATE` button) and then in the menu next to the button (the three vertical dots) there is a `Logfile` option.

Comment: @Marijn Thanks for clarifying, however I have already put the whole output of the logfile into the paste. I'm not sure exactly what Ulrike Fischer is looking for.

Comment: @Concerto I didn't look at the pastebin before, now I understand :) when LaTeX runs it produces two kinds of logs: terminal output and a .log file. The two logs are largely the same, however the actual log file contains more information, indicated by the phrase _(see the transcript file for additional information) Transcript written on document.log._ in your pastebin document. So VerbTeX provides only the terminal output and not the actual log. In this case that means that the font tracing information is missing, which is what Ulrike was asking about.

Comment: Anyway, what the terminal output _does_ show are all the warnings `OpenType feature 'Ligatures=Common' (liga) not available for font 'Linux Libertine O'` . On my (Ubuntu) desktop it works without problems, and these warnings do not occur, so apparently there is something wrong with either the font file that VerbTeX uses or some kind of configuration issue on their side that prevents the ligature information from being read and used.

Comment: I've emailed the VerbTeX developer (who conveniently lives not more than 200km away from me). I'm currently waiting for a reply, and will answer my post as soon as I know more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Disclaimer: I'm the developer of the VerbTeX app]

You can find a working example at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XeTeX which shows an example including ligatures using the *Linux Libertine O Italic* font.

Anyway, there seems to be an issue with the *normal* font. Maybe it has to do with the 85% support for ligatures mentioned at https://fontlibrary.org/en/font/linux-libertine.

In any case: We'll look into that in detail. In the meantime you can use an own font file (.otf or .ttf) which should solve this issue as well.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer this. That means concretely, I'll download the font from the Libertine Project, and then I'll have 100% support, correct?    PS: I have infact used Linux Libertine O Italic for the majority of the time, BECAUSE it has these amazing historic ligatures.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. We just tested it with the downloaded font 'LinLibertine_R.otf' and ligatures and old styles work correctly. Please let us know if you have any questions.

Comment: Peter, it now works for every type of ligature and number style. Thank you very much. Have a wonderful evening.